# Logging Exceptions and Redirect to Specific Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, error-handling

I am using `HandleErrorInfo()` to handle errors.
I need to update URL when `HandleErrorInfo()` redirects to the Error page.

`www.mysite.com/Error` instead of `www.mysite.com/Update`

Also i need to know how i log the exception.

Web.config:

```
  <customErrors mode="On"  defaultRedirect ="~/Admin/Error"></customErrors>
```

Admin Controller:

```
public ActionResult Error()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: What you mean by update url ? You want to redirect to `Update/Index` ?

Comment: @Shyju, Thank you for your help... No, See. Say you are in page www.site.come/update when any error occurs the url still www.site.come/update ... i need to www.site.come/Admin/Error

Comment: @Lucy I'm not sure you should change the URL to your error page. If the user tries to refresh the page in their browser they'll always get the error page instead of the original path trying again.

Comment: I tried ... the URL is not changing ....